# Insert HTML tag inside jQuery string of a wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem, we are using a MAP wordpress plugin, and It looks like this on frontend

[image]

What my client wants is to make the bracket (and the word inside it) smaller.

Here's the map code in the back end

[image]

```
{
"mapwidth": "980",
"mapheight": "600",
"action": "tooltip",
"fillcolor": "#343f4b",
"maxscale": "3",
"customcss": ".mapplic-portrait .mapplic-sidebar{\n\tmin-height: 360px; }\n",
"fullscreen": false,
"hovertip": true,
"hovertipdesc": false,
"smartip": false,
"deeplinking": true,
"linknewtab": false,
"minimap": true,
"animations": false,
"zoom": true,
"zoombuttons": true,
"clearbutton": true,
"zoomoutclose": false,
"closezoomout": false,
"mousewheel": true,
"mapfill": false,
"sidebar": true,
"search": false,
"searchdescription": false,
"alphabetic": true,
"thumbholder": false,
"sidebartoggle": false,
"filtersopened": false,
"highlight": false,
"levels": [
    {
        "id": "usa",
        "title": "USA",
        "map": "//website.com/wp-content/plugins/mapplic/maps/usa.svg",
        "minimap": "http://website.com/wp-content/plugins/mapplic/maps/usa-mini.jpg"
    }
],
"styles": [],
"categories": [],
"locations": [
    {
        ... other details removed
    },
    {
        "title": "NY [Westchester County] = ConEdison",
        "id": "nyc2",
        "pin": "hidden",
        "link": "/residential/nyc/",
        "action": "open-link",
        "x": "0.8833",
        "y": "0.3156",
        "level": "usa",
        "color": "#343f4b"
    }
]
```

}

What I want to achieve is something like this;

```
        {
        "title": "NY <span class="\bracket\">[Westchester County]</span> = ConEdison",
        "id": "nyc2",
        "level": "usa",
        "color": "#343f4b"
    }
```

I want to add a class to a bracket so that I can manipulate its style.

**[update]** Here's what happens if I add the span inside the title:

[image]

**[Update 2]** Yes it is treated as text. and there's no other option in plugin to change or add style to any of the wordings inside that line.
[image]

What is the best approach to this? How can I make that possible? I have limited knowledge of JavaScript or jQuery. I would appreciate your responses.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Map library is rendering the content as text. You can force it to be rendered as html after the map is generated. As I checked, those elements are in  tag so I convert h4 texts into HTML. You may make it more specific if h4 is not enough:

```
var h4Elements = document.querySelectorAll('h4');

// Loop through each h4 element
for (var i = 0; i < h4Elements.length; i++) {
  var h4Element = h4Elements[i];
  
  // Get the existing text content of the h4 element
  var existingText = h4Element.textContent;

  // Update the content to include the HTML span tags
  h4Element.innerHTML = existingText; // This will replace the text with HTML
}
```

Comment: Hi @ali thank you for your reply! really appreciate this. unfortunately, the plugin is not allowing us to add any other script, https://snipboard.io/itJ50W.jpg , https://snipboard.io/9xGoX6.jpg will this be safe to add this on function? hmm but it will apply to other pages with H4 as well if I add this in function right?

Comment: I think using this code is safe for all h4 tags because this only converts text to html where in all other cases mostly there are html by default however you can be more specific like `document.querySelectorAll('.mapplic-element h4')`

Comment: I tried this on my local files and the code is working properly. There's just something blocking it from running when it is being applied to the server.  there's something conflicting.

Comment: Hi Ali. just a quick question, locally everything is working, but not on the server. I am trying to solve it by adding noConflict() but nothing is happening, Just asking if you have any other suggestion aside from noConflict(). Here's what your code currently looks like....=>=>   jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var h4Elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mapplic-element a h4');
 for (var i = 0; i < h4Elements.length; i++) {
  var h4Element = h4Elements[i];
  var existingText = h4Element.textContent;
  h4Element.innerHTML = existingText;
 }
})(jQuery);

Comment: I checked your website Jquery was not present

Comment: yeah but actually if you save the page and run it from your pc, you'll see that the menu and the code are working.  That's why I think something is conflicting or something is blocking the code.